# Consistency when removing items from boost multi-index using an inner iterator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Suppose I am iterating over a `boost::multi_index` using one of the two indices. Then if I start iterating using the other index and erasing an element according some criteria, does that invalidate the upper iterator?

E.g.,

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace std;

struct person {
    string name;
    string last_name;
    int age;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
    person,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<member<person, string, &person::name> >,
        ordered_non_unique<member<person, int, &person::age> >,
        sequenced<>
    >
> PersonCollection;


int main()
{
     PersonCollection pc;
     //insert some elements into pc
     struct person kk = {"John", "Doe", 15};
     pc.insert(kk);
     kk = {"John", "Doe2", 17};
     pc.insert(kk);
     kk = {"John", "Doe3", 34};
     pc.insert(kk);
     kk = {"John", "Smith", 34};
     pc.insert(kk);

     auto &index0 = pc.get<0>();
     auto range0 = index0.equal_range("John");
     while (range0.first != range0.second) {
         auto &index1 = pc.get<1>();
         auto range1 = index1.equal_range(34);
         while (range1.first != range1.second) {
             if (range1.first->last_name == "Smith")
                 range1.first = index1.erase(range1.first);
             else
                 ++range1.first;    
         }
    ++range0.first;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So in this case, is the `range0` iterator always valid? Thanks!

Comment: Don't post "dream code" here and expect answers. Make your code correct and self-contained instead

Comment: @sehe sorry for that, I edited the code to be self-contained.

Comment: Much better. Now I'll have to remove the ranty parts from my answer :(

Comment: @sehe sorry but I made one small correction again

Comment: No problem. I just posted my answer that was long in draft. Removing the ranty bits in 5 minutes (so they're in edit history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is likely fundamentally flawed. I think this is because you used confusing names (`range0` etc.). You outer loop is unrelated to the inner loops so, you could have removed it (saving time doing useless repeats). Here's a clarified rewrite:

```
auto& ageIdx = pc.get<byAge>();

auto namerange = pc.get<byName>().equal_range("John");
for (auto name_it = namerange.first, end = namerange.second; name_it != end; ++name_it) {

    auto agerange = ageIdx.equal_range(34);

    for (auto age_it = agerange.first, end = agerange.second; age_it != end;) {
        if (age_it->last_name == "Smith")
            age_it = ageIdx.erase(age_it);
        else
            ++age_it;    
    }
}
```

Indeed  this is unsafe. The `name_it` might be invalidated. Fix it:

```
for (auto name_it = namerange.first, end = namerange.second; name_it != end;) {
    ++name_it;
```

> Note the code will remove remove 'Ruby Smith (age 34)' just fine. The 'John' criterion is never used, so:

Even better, fix it to the equivalent:

```
auto agerange = pc.get<byAge>().equal_range(34);

for (auto age_it = agerange.first, end = agerange.second; age_it != end;) {
    std::cout << *age_it << "\n";
    if (age_it->last_name == "Smith")
        age_it = ageIdx.erase(age_it);
    else
        ++age_it;    
}
```

### Thinking out of the box

Really looks like you want to delete by some "primary" key (name, last_name, age). Say what you mean:

```
pc.erase(pc.find(boost::make_tuple("Smith", "John", 34))); // just the one
```

That's **all** of the code.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/706109e2831d1bda)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct person {
    std::string name;
    std::string last_name;
    int age;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, person const& p) {
        return os << "{" << p.name << ", " << p.last_name << ", " << p.age << "}";
    }
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
    person,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct primaryKey>,
            bmi::composite_key<person,
                bmi::member<person, std::string, &person::last_name>,
                bmi::member<person, std::string, &person::name>,
                bmi::member<person, int,         &person::age>
            >
        >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct byAge>,  bmi::member<person, int, &person::age> >
    >
> PersonCollection;

int main() {
    PersonCollection pc {
        person { "John",    "Lennon",    34 },
        person { "Elliot",  "Gardiner",  72 },
        person { "John",    "Smith",     34 },
        person { "Lucy",    "Greenstle", 34 },
        person { "Gold",    "Smith",     34 },
        person { "Nicolai", "Josuttis",  42 }
    };

    auto& idx = pc.get<primaryKey>();

    // print
    std::copy(pc.begin(), pc.end(), std::ostream_iterator<person>(std::cout << "\n", "; "));

    pc.erase(pc.find(boost::make_tuple("Smith", "John", 34))); // just the one
    // print
    std::copy(pc.begin(), pc.end(), std::ostream_iterator<person>(std::cout << "\n", "; "));

    auto range = idx.equal_range(boost::make_tuple("Smith", "John")); // any age
    for (auto f=range.first, l=range.second; f!=l;)
        f = idx.erase(f);
    // print
    std::copy(pc.begin(), pc.end(), std::ostream_iterator<person>(std::cout << "\n", "; "));

    range = idx.equal_range(boost::make_tuple("Smith")); // any age/first name
    for (auto f=range.first, l=range.second; f!=l;)
        f = idx.erase(f);

    // print
    std::copy(pc.begin(), pc.end(), std::ostream_iterator<person>(std::cout << "\n", "; "));
}
```

Prints:

```
{Elliot, Gardiner, 72}; {Lucy, Greenstle, 34}; {Nicolai, Josuttis, 42}; {John, Lennon, 34}; {Gold, Smith, 34}; {John, Smith, 34}; 
{Elliot, Gardiner, 72}; {Lucy, Greenstle, 34}; {Nicolai, Josuttis, 42}; {John, Lennon, 34}; {Gold, Smith, 34}; 
{Elliot, Gardiner, 72}; {Lucy, Greenstle, 34}; {Nicolai, Josuttis, 42}; {John, Lennon, 34}; {Gold, Smith, 34}; 
{Elliot, Gardiner, 72}; {Lucy, Greenstle, 34}; {Nicolai, Josuttis, 42}; {John, Lennon, 34};
```

Comment: that's actually what I want: outer loop not related to the inner loop. Question is if you erase stuff in the inner loop, does that affect the outer loop. It probably does, so this is not a good construction. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: It does, and my first answer shows how to do it legally. (Pro tip: make the sample meaningful, so we can understand what you need)

Comment: then you miss the first item, no?

Comment: No. It's not used. If you want to, do it before the increment. My code does that: it does **all** the usage of `*name_it`, i.e. _none_, before incrementing. The point is to increment before invalidation. (See the pro tip added to my previous comment)

Comment: What if I want to remove "John Smith"s too?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was not clear enough. What if on the first step of outer loop you calculate some variable, and depending on that erase stuff in the inner loop. In that case your first solution misses the first iteration of the outer loop

Comment: @hovo What if you show an example that makes it clear what you mean (see the protip again). And no in that case no iterations are missed.

Comment: ok. let me get back to it tomorrow. Have to run. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider posting it as a new question, because I get the feeling the change would invalidate the answer, and that's not so nice

Comment: I posted the other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841872/boost-multi-index-iterators-validity-status-after-erasure-in-inner-loop