# boost multi_index iterator's validity status after erasure in inner loop

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Is this legal? I.e., is the outer iterator `range0.first` invalidated by erasing stuff using the inner iterator `range1.first`? Thanks!

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace std;

struct person {
    string name;
    string last_name;
    int age;
};

typedef multi_index_container<
person,
    indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<member<person, string, &person::name> >,
    ordered_non_unique<member<person, int, &person::age> >,
    sequenced<>
    >
    > PersonCollection;


int main()
{
    PersonCollection pc;
    //insert some elements into pc
    struct person kk = {"John", "Doe", 15};
    pc.insert(kk);
    kk = {"John", "Doe2", 17};
    pc.insert(kk);
    kk = {"John", "Doe3", 34};
    pc.insert(kk);
    kk = {"John", "Smith", 15};
    pc.insert(kk);

    auto &index0 = pc.get<0>();
    auto range0 = index0.equal_range("John");
    while (range0.first != range0.second) {
        auto &index1 = pc.get<1>();
        auto range1 = index1.equal_range(range0.first->age);
        while (range1.first != range1.second) {
            if (range1.first->last_name == "Smith")
                range1.first = index1.erase(range1.first);
            else
                ++range1.first;    
        }
        ++range0.first;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to achieve. Why would you want to delete all persons named "Smith" having the the same age as anyone whose first name happens to be "John"?

Comment: :) well, that's not the exact problem I'm facing right now, but very similar

Comment: And no its not legal. Even if you arrange the outer increment to be before any erase, the outer iterator might get invalidated as soon as there are more than one people named "John"